# DeserializationError when trying to load my saved data to my new database

Tags: python, django, database

So before I changed databases from sqlite to postgresql, I performed `python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json` which saved a `datadump.json` file and `dumpdata.json` file in my app directory.:

To retrieve this data in my new database I performed `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json` however it returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 69, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 109, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 166, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 88, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 81, in Deserializer
    objects = json.loads(stream_or_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/zorgan/Desktop/project/app/datadump.json': Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Any idea what the problem is?

snippet from `datadump.json`:

```
 [{"model": "polls.question", "pk": 1, "fields": {"question_text": "What's your name?", "date": "2018-04-02T03:22:20.190", "radio": true...
```

Comment: Without any more detailed information on `datadump.json` this is quite much impossible to answer.

Comment: I've added a snippet of `datadump.json` in my edit - I can't add it all in as it is quite large. Is there any specific data I can show you to give better information?